# Python3 CSV writerows, TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, typeerror, kaggle

I am translating the following Kaggle code into Python3.4:

In the final lines when outputting a CSV file,

```
predictions_file = open("myfirstforest.csv", "wb")
open_file_object = csv.writer(predictions_file)
open_file_object.writerow(["PassengerId","Survived"])
open_file_object.writerows(zip(ids, output))
predictions_file.close()
print('Done.')
```

there's a Type Error

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

which occurs at the line `open_file_object.writerow(["PassengerId","Survived"])`.

I believe this is because Opening a file in binary mode to write csv data to doesn't work in Python 3. However, adding `encoding='utf8'` in the `open()` line doesn't work either.

What is the standard way to do this in Python3.4?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Creating a CSV file is different between Python 2 and Python 3 (as a look into the docs for the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) would have shown):

Instead of

```
predictions_file = open("myfirstforest.csv", "wb")
```

you need to use

```
predictions_file = open("myfirstforest.csv", "w", newline="")
```

(And you should use a context manager to handle the closing of the file for you, in case an error does occur):

```
with open("myfirstforest.csv", "w", newline="") as predictions_file:
    # do stuff
# No need to close the file
```

Comment: "as a look into the docs for the csv module would have shown" I realized this (and mentioned it in the original question, in English). I didn't understand the error was caused by `newline=""'`, which is why I wanted a clarification. I apologize for causing you such distress.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang for clarity: `'wb'` opens the file in a binary mode and therefore `.write()` expects binary data such as `bytes` object, not `str` that is Unicode in Python 3. `'w'` opens the file in a text mode: `.write()` expects `str`. Python 3.5 produces more intelligible error message: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. `newline=""` is unrelated to the issue but it is recommended for `csv` files (`csv` module uses `b'\r\n'` even on Unix; `newline=''` allows to write newlines without the usual universal newlines mode conversion (`'\n'` -> `os.linesep`)).